# How to add a GUI that will allow the user to add numbers, then click sort which will sort the code

Tags: python, tkinter

Please help with my gui here is the code:
I want to be able to have the user type in numbers in the entry field and be able to click add, then pressing thee sort button so that the SELECTION SORT sorts it.

```
title = "Selection Sort GUI"
A = [64, 25, 12, 22, 11]
# Traverse through all array elements
def sort(A):
    for i in range(len(A)):

        # Find the minimum element in remaining
        # unsorted array
        smallest = i
        for j in range(i+1, len(A)):
            if A[smallest] > A[j]:
                smallest = j

        # Swap the found minimum element with
        # the first element
        A[i], A[smallest] = A[smallest], A[i]

# Printing sorted array
print ("Sorted array:")
print (A)

master = tk.Tk()
master.title("Dans Selection Sort")
passwordEntry = tk.Entry(master)
passwordEntry.grid(row=0, column=1)
tk.Label(master, text='Enter Number: ', font='bold',).grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Button(master, text='Add to Array', command=lambda: sort(A)).grid(row=1, column=0)
tk.Button(master, text='Sort', command=lambda: sort(A)).grid(row=1, column=1)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the type of help you need? What is this program doing, and how is it different from what you want?

Comment: built-in function `A = sorted(A)` or `in-place` sorting `A.sort()`

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, I recommend a class based structure, stealing from https://stackoverflow.com/a/17470842/1942837

```py
import tkinter as tk

class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        # init
        self.passwordEntry = tk.Entry(self)
        label = tk.Label(self, text='Enter Number: ', font='bold',)
        btn_add = tk.Button(self, text='Add to Array',
                            command=self.add_to_array)
        btn_sort = tk.Button(self, text='Sort',
                             command=self.sort)

        # layout
        self.passwordEntry.grid(row=0, column=1)
        label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        btn_add.grid(row=1, column=0)
        btn_sort.grid(row=1, column=1)

        # data
        self.values = list()

    def add_to_array(self):
        # called when the user presses the Add to Array button
        # (1) Fetch the Entry input:
        entry = self.passwordEntry.get()
        # (2) Add to our data list
        self.values.append(entry)
        print('values is now', self.values)

    def sort(self):
        # called when user presses Sort button
        # no need for special function, just use the inbuilt sorted()
        print('sorted', sorted(self.values))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    master = tk.Tk()
    master.title("Dans Selection Sort")
    MainApplication(master).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    master.mainloop()
```

A key concept you missed is that you need to keep the array you want to sort somewhere, here as a list called self.values. I will leave it up to you to display this in the gui, here I just print it to the console. Instead of a custom sort function, I simply use the built-in [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) function.

As an alternative to a class would be to store the self.values as a global list and then have two functions that access that global list.

Let me know if any part of the above code is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

There is already `A = sorted(A)` or in-place `A.sort()`

Rest needs only few changes. And maybe it needs better organization.

I use one `Label` to display `array` and other `Label` to display `Sorted`/`Added`

`Button` can send array to function using `lambda` but it can't get result - it would need to use `global` to assing result to external variable  - so I skiped `lambda` and I access directly global array.

---

Minimal working code

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- classes ---

# ... empty ...

# --- functions ---

def sort():
    data.sort()  # built-in sorting `in-place`

    label_msg['text'] = "Sorted"
    label_result['text'] = str(data)

def add():
    data.append(int(entry.get()))

    label_msg['text'] = "Added"
    label_result['text'] = str(data)

# --- main ---

# - data - 

data = [64, 25, 12, 22, 11]

# - code - 

master = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(master, text='Enter Number: ')
label.grid(row=0, column=0)

entry = tk.Entry(master)
entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

button_add = tk.Button(master, text='Add to Array', command=add)
button_add.grid(row=1, column=0)

button_sort = tk.Button(master, text='Sort', command=sort)
button_sort.grid(row=1, column=1)

label_msg = tk.Label(master, text='')
label_msg.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)

label_result = tk.Label(master, text=str(data))
label_result.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)

master.mainloop()
```